# Generate random numbers on the fly using Intel MKL

Tags: c, random, intel, intel-mkl

I'm trying to generate discrete random numbers with uniform distribution using Intel MKL.
The function `viRngUniformBits32` generates `n` random integers.
I want to generate random numbers on the fly rather than generating them `n` at a time.
I tried this but obviously it doesn't work. I call the function 5 times and it outputs the same value.
I assume it is generating the first number in the sequence every time based on the seed value.
Now how do I modify this so that every time I call this method, I get a `random` number

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mkl.h"
int main()
{
    unsigned int out;
    VSLStreamStatePtr stream;
    vslNewStream(&stream,VSL_BRNG_MCG31,2);
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        //FORMAT viRngUniformBits32( method, stream, n, r );
        viRngUniformBits32(VSL_RNG_METHOD_UNIFORMBITS32_STD,stream,1,&out);
        printf("%u\t",out);
    }
        printf("\n");
    vslDeleteStream(&stream);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the return values of `vslNewStream` and `viRngUniformBits32`?

Comment: @jaket: That is just the status

Comment: The return values can indicate if the stream is invalid. Seems like an easy thing to verify.

Comment: Makes sense. I just tried to print the return code. The doc says the return code is of type integer. So i used `%d` and I get a value as `-1014`. I'm supposed to get '0' for successful completion

Comment: Just found out that `-1014` means `VSL_RNG_ERROR_BRNG_NOT_SUPPORTED`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `viRngUniformBits32` does not support the BRNG `VSL_BRNG_MCG31`.

So I used `VSL_BRNG_MT19937` and it works without any errors.

Thanks to `jaket` for reminding me to look at the error code.